# RavenDB slow reading

Tags: c#, .net, database, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB but I noticed my database is very slow when reading. Here is how i query to my database:

```
        IEnumerable<Reduced> items;
        Filter filter = (Filter)Filter;

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {

            var query = session.Query<eBayItem,eBayItemIndexer>().Where(y => y.Price <= filter.MaxPrice && y.Price >= filter.MinPrice); 
            query = filter.Keywords.ToArray()
            .Aggregate(query, (q, term) =>
                q.Search(xx => xx.Title, term, options: SearchOptions.And));
           if (filter.ExcludedKeywords.Count > 0)
            {
                query = filter.ExcludedKeywords.ToArray().Aggregate(query, (q, exterm) =>
                q.Search(it => it.Title, exterm, options: SearchOptions.Not));
            }
           items = query.AsProjection<Reduced>().ToList();
           Console.WriteLine("Query: " + query.ToString());
           Console.WriteLine("Results: " + items.Count());
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Query time: " + watch.Elapsed.Milliseconds + " ms");
        return items;
```

**Output:**

- Query: Price_Range:[* TO Dx600] AND Price_Range:[Dx400 TO NULL] AND Title:(Canon) AND Title:(MP) AND Title:(Black) -Title:(G1) -Title:(T3)
- Results: 3
- Query time: 365 ms

**Indexing:**

```
public class eBayItemIndexer : AbstractIndexCreationTask<eBayItem>
{
    public eBayItemIndexer()
    {
        Map = contentItems =>
            from contentItem in contentItems
            select new { contentItem.Title, contentItem.Price };

        Index(x => x.Title, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(x => x.Price, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);


        TransformResults = (database, items) =>
            from contentItem in items
            select new { contentItem.Id };
    }
}
```

**Initialization:**

```
        documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore() { DataDirectory = "test.db" };
        documentStore.Initialize();
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(eBayItemIndexer).Assembly, documentStore);
        documentStore.Configuration.TransactionMode = Raven.Abstractions.Data.TransactionMode.Lazy;
        documentStore.Configuration.AllowLocalAccessWithoutAuthorization = true;
```

Is their something wrong with the code that makes it slow ?

Answer (score 0):

`EmbeddableDocumentStore` is probably the problem. To be rather more exact, it looks like you are initializing the store, then immediately calling the query. The first few queries on an index are always going to be somewhat slower.

Comment: After 1h of keeping the program idle, the query still takes 350 ms on avarage.

Comment: It has to do something with EmbeddableDocumentStore though, hosting a server local, querty time is around 20ms

Comment: @Ayende I am trying to use the db in embedded mode also, and my init times are horrible.  Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this, and I was using the dedicated server (not embedded). The issue I found was that I was initializing the document store at the time of the query instead of beforehand, on application load.

If running on a native program, initialize the document store during the startup process and hold it as a singleton until you're going to close the program. You only need one document store, but you should create a new session for each atomic operation.

If you're running this in a web app, register the document store on application start in the dependency injection container of your choice as a singleton scope.

Either of these options will initialize the document store early and keep it open. Then you have only to open a session for each query. When querying for about 300 records by a common Guid out of 2 million total records, I went from 2+ seconds to about 150ms. If you have a smaller database that number should drop significantly.